# How to determine if the series $\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{3+\cos(2^n)} $ converges or diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convergence-divergence, fractions

$\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{3+\cos(2^n)} $

I know that $2\le 3+\cos(2^n)\le4 \Rightarrow  \frac{1}{4}\le\frac{1}{3+\cos(2^n)} \le1/2 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{3+\cos(2^n)} \ge  \frac{1}{4}$.
Which test can I use to determine whether the series converges or not?

Comment: If $\sum a_n$ converges then $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: From your work, $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{3 + \cos (2^n )}}}  := \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to  + \infty } \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{1}{{3 + \cos (2^n )}}}  \ge \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to  + \infty } \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{1}{4}}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to  + \infty } \frac{N}{4} =  + \infty .
$$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy so can i say that because the limit of $a_n = 1/4$ is not zero then the series for 1/4 does not converge then by the comparison test the original series $\sum 1/[3+cos(2^n)]$ does not converge ?

Comment: Argue with $a_n=\frac1  {3+\cos (2^{n})}$ instead of $a_n=\frac 1 4$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy can i say that the limit of $a_n = 1/[3+cos( 2^n)$  is not 0 by the sandwhich theorem? how can i find the limit of this a_n ?

Comment: $a_n$ does not have a limit. But assuming that it tends to $0$ leads to a contradiction, so the series is divergent.